# Problem load view from controller in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to load a main view from my controller in CodeIgniter 3.0, but instead of showing the view, the page shows the "Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string", and the view I want to show is on the top of my page not in the center of my page.

Here is the error screenshot :
[image: Here is the error screenshot]

This is my controller:

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
    $data['utama'] = $this->load->view('spvcoll/v_list');
    $data['judul'] = 'List Assign';
    $this->load->view('v_index',$data);
}else{
    redirect('c_index');
}
```

Here I want to call the variable:

`<?php echo $utama;?>`

Comment: instead of `$data['utama'] = $this->load->view('spvcoll/v_list');` try `$data['utama'] = $this->load->view('spvcoll/v_list', true);`

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to call `$this->load->view('spvcoll/v_list');` from a view file instead of passing the string into the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY This

```
$data['utama'] = $this->load->view('spvcoll/v_list', TRUE);
```

Instead of

```
$data['utama'] = $this->load->view('spvcoll/v_list');
```